# Crash when set CAMetalLayer.presentsWithTransaction=true in background thread

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

When set `metalLayer.presentsWithTransaction = true`, and when I call `nextDrawable.present()` in bg thread (our rendering thread is not main thread), the app sometimes will crash with:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'

Expected: App will not crash....The rendering should be ok.

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1aa30a5ac __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1be38442c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1be60ad4c -[NSISEngine tryToOptimizeReturningMutuallyExclusiveConstraints]
3  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1be60aa20 -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding]
4  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1be60a4f8 -[NSISEngine optimize]
5  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1be605b34 -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications]
6  UIKitCore                      0x1ad13eef4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews]
7  UIKitCore                      0x1ad151dd4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
8  QuartzCore                     0x1ad65b280 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
9  QuartzCore                     0x1ad65b73c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
10 QuartzCore                     0x1ad66fb64 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
11 QuartzCore                     0x1ad5b7114 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
12 QuartzCore                     0x1ad5e2418 CA::Transaction::commit()
13 Flutter                        0x1032e4778 (Missing)
14 Flutter                        0x1035b85ec (Missing)
15 Flutter                        0x1035b9094 (Missing)
16 Flutter                        0x1035b88b0 (Missing)
17 Flutter                        0x1035bedb0 (Missing)
18 Flutter                        0x1032ef46c (Missing)
19 Flutter                        0x1032f13e0 (Missing)
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa288050 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa287c50 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa2870c4 __CFRunLoopDoTimers
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa281178 __CFRunLoopRun
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa2804bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
25 Flutter                        0x1032f12bc (Missing)
26 Flutter                        0x1032f0c44 (Missing)
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1f185aca8 _pthread_start
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1f1863788 thread_start
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: The exception literally says that you cannot do this on background thread. The solution to this is to not touch layer properties on background thread.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Do you mean I can't set presentsWithTransaction to metal layer on bg thread, or I can't present drawable on bg thread? ^_^

Comment: I think you can present on any thread, you just can't change layer properties on anything other than UI thread.

Comment: Thx for your reply and suggestion. I will have a try recently ^_^

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Emm I tried..... And It will still crash

Comment: Run it from under xcode and set a "thrown" Objective C exception breakpoint. You will then break in the line that's causing a problem.

Comment: emm I didn't catch up any exception.... The only exception catched just from runloop.... I don't know why... I didn't modify any layer layout properties.... Very strange..... I modify my question desc. You can check that stack trace.....

Comment: You are changing something about the layer or a view on the background, that's the only explanation I have. Try to set breakpoints in all places you actually change view bounds or any other properties and see if it gets hit on main thread or some other thread

Comment: I use method swizzing to get that. And I hook setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout and layoutSublayers of CALayer. I found that If I set `presentsWithTransaction=true` and call `drawable.present()` from sub thread, these methods will trigger in that sub thread so I will get this crash...... I don't know why these method will trigger, because I didn't call these method in sub thread.......